# How to change storyboard/ View while switching to static library in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, static-libraries

I am new to iOS, started working on static libraries.

I have a main project and a static library project. I have added my library projects header and lib.a in the main project. I am able to call library project's methods from main project. But library project has a storyboard named: LibStory.storyboard while main project has storyboard: MainStory.storyboard.

When I start my app view starts from MainStory.storyboard then I have to call my library project and start LibStory.storyboard. When I start storyboard of lib project, I get this error:

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

LibStoryBViewController is in lib project. Do I need to add "LibStory.storyboard" in main project, I did that too still not working.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LibStory" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"te"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

This is the code in lib project to call storyboard. Please suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: Are choosing one of the storyboards in code when your app is launching or MainStory is always default based on app settings? This error appears when you are trying to show view controller to early.

Comment: Initially I started with MainStory then when I click a button in MainStory I want to start storyboard of static library's storyboard.